# What does this song quote mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence, songs

"All the good girls they go to heaven, but the bad girls they get backstage"

The first sentence is fine, but I don't understand what it mean to go "backstage"

Song name is Backstage.

Comment: "Backstage" means the area of a music venue that's restricted to the performers and crew. The meaning of the line is literal, with the implication that the girls are invited there for sordid reasons.

Comment: It might help to listen to more of the song. I am not familiar with it, but I expect that @jsheeran above is right.

Comment: It means the "bad girls" get to go backstage after concerts to provide to the musicians with particularly intimate forms of physical entertainment. The current answer is incorrect. They are engaging in acts that are likely to get them pregnant, not famous.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because meanings of lyrics, poems, jokes is considered off-topic

Comment: @PeterCordes You made a duplicate to a question in the future. While possible, it's weird.

Comment: @Mitch: Duplicate doesn't always just mean "you shouldn't have asked this, see this duplicate".  It means "the best answer(s) to this question is/are over here".   On StackOverflow, it happens fairly often that a question is re-asked in a well-written way and gets better answers than an old version, so it makes sense to close the old questions as duplicates of the new ones.  It's not weird if you think of a StackExchange site as a repository of knowledge that you're maintaining, rather than a time-ordered list of Q&As.

Comment: @Mitch several days ago I flagged the same thing to the mods. Why should a poorly expressed question with, objectively speaking, bad or imprecise answers be prized above the newer question by virtue of age? See Shog9's answer on meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/223820

Answer (score 1):

Find the full lyrics here [here](http://www.beelyrics.com/n/neffex/backstage.html). And here they are in all their glory:

> All the good girls you take out for dinner
>
> but all the bad girls you take out for liquor
>
> All the good girls they don't pull the trigger
>
> But all that bad girls they pull it much quicker
>
> It's never too late to get down and party
>
> Switching from good to bad cuz your naughty
>
> Feel it inside oh inside your body
>
> Let it come out with shots of Bacardi
>
> Just let your body go
>
> We'll take it nice and slow
>
> Just let your mind be free
>
> And come in close to me
>
> Oh the good girls they go to heaven but the bad girls they get backstage
>
> All the good girls they act like beginners but all the bad girls they know that they're sinners
>
> All the good girls are really good kissers but all the bad girls are really good strippers
>
> Baby don't slow it down let's keep going
>
> I think that you and I should lose clothing
>
> I think that all good girls just need coaching
>
> So let me show ya how! Let's get on it!
>
> Just let your body go
>
> We'll take it nice and slow
>
> Just let your mind be free
>
> And come in close to me
>
> Oh, the good girls they go to heaven but the bad girls they get backstage.

Good grief! Leaving aside the fact that the lyrics are misogynist drivel, it's some sort of manifestation of a young (male) musician's fantasy about women/impressionable girls.

'Backstage' is the part of an entertainment venue the general audience cannot see, which is restricted to performers and crew, and is seen as the Holy Grail (the goal) for fans wanting to meet (well, more than meet, really) their idols. It's off stage, and thus highly desirable for people who want to be there. Whoever wrote this seems to feel that being/getting backstage is good.

The question was restricted to what 'get backstage' means, so I shall confine my answer to the preceding paragraph.

Answer (score -3):

> God selects a limited number of faithful Christians who, after their
>   death, will be resurrected to life in heaven. (1 Peter 1:3, 4)

**go to heaven** means die, Good girls die first.

---

**backstage**

> in the area behind the stage in a theatre, especially the rooms in
>   which actors change their clothes or where equipment is kept:

To me, it means they become actresses that have a great many opportunities that make them famous, which implies that they get rich.

Comment: Getting a pass backstage is more of an opportunity to meet and party with famous people.

Comment: As @arp says. The information is correct but the interpretation is pretty much completely incorrect.